# Java. Read file from FTP but DON'T download it whole

Tags: java, file, ftp, stream

I need to read CSV file header from FTP.

As these files can be very huge, I don't need to download them.

Is there a way to read first line of CSV file from FTP and abort connection?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just read only the first line, ignore the remnant and close the stream. A smart FTP client won't buffer the *entire* stream in memory before providing anything for read.

Assuming you're using [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html):

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
String firstLine = null;

try {
    InputStream stream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(ftpFile.getName());
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
    firstLine = reader.readLine();
} finally {
    if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}

doYourThingWith(firstLine);
```