# connect to ftp server using jdbc ftp driver

Tags: java, jdbc, ftp

I am looking for an example in Java to connect to ftp server and retrieve data from CSV file.

Comment: Why do you want to use JDBC for FTP?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is anything like a JDBC driver for FTP, FTP is for retrieving or storing files on a remote server, JDBC is an API for database access.

Comment: Well, color me surprised, there turns out to be a JDBC FTP driver... I have no idea why anyone would want to use it. In any case, your question is entirely unclear/vague. Check the documentation of that JDBC FTP driver, and ask a more specific question if its documentation doesn't help you.

Comment: understand...actually i have a csv file on FTP server and i want to read the file content using java..can you please help me to suggest a better approach

Comment: "read the file content" is still too broad. For reading file contents, you do not need JDBC. State your constraints. + Edit your question to ask about your real problem/task, rather than asking about a purported solution. Your question looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java. Read file from FTP but DON'T download it whole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834758/java-read-file-from-ftp-but-dont-download-it-whole)